# Splitting a factor at a space in R

Tags: r

I want to split x (which is a factor)

```
dd = data.frame(x = c("29-4-2014 06:00:00", "9-4-2014 12:00:00", "9-4-2014 00:00:00", "6-5-2014 00:00:00" ,"7-4-2014 00:00:00" , "29-5-2014 00:00:00"))

          x
29-4-2014 06:00:00
 9-4-2014 12:00:00
 9-4-2014 00:00:00
 6-5-2014 00:00:00
 7-4-2014 00:00:00
29-5-2014 00:00:00
```

at the horizontal space and get two columns as:

```
  x.date   x.time
29-4-2014 06:00:00
 9-4-2014 12:00:00
 9-4-2014 00:00:00
 6-5-2014 00:00:00
 7-4-2014 00:00:00
29-5-2014 00:00:00
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to treat these as actual dates?  check out the package `lubridate`

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald I'd love to, I am not aware of that. Example on how to proceed would be great!

Comment: i worked out an example below, @Duna. HTH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach using `lubridate`:

```
dd = data.frame(x = c("29-4-2014 06:00:00", "9-4-2014 12:00:00", "9-4-2014 00:00:00", "6-5-2014 00:00:00" ,"7-4-2014 00:00:00" , "29-5-2014 00:00:00"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note the use of `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, which prevents your dates from being read as factors.

```
library(lubridate)

dd2 <- transform(dd,x2 = dmy_hms(x))
transform(dd2, the_year = year(x2))

                   x                  x2 the_year
1 29-4-2014 06:00:00 2014-04-29 06:00:00     2014
2  9-4-2014 12:00:00 2014-04-09 12:00:00     2014
3  9-4-2014 00:00:00 2014-04-09 00:00:00     2014
4  6-5-2014 00:00:00 2014-05-06 00:00:00     2014
5  7-4-2014 00:00:00 2014-04-07 00:00:00     2014
6 29-5-2014 00:00:00 2014-05-29 00:00:00     2014
```

Answer (score 4):

`strsplit` is typically used here, but you can also use `read.table`:

```
read.table(text = as.character(dd$x))
#          V1       V2
# 1 29-4-2014 06:00:00
# 2  9-4-2014 12:00:00
# 3  9-4-2014 00:00:00
# 4  6-5-2014 00:00:00
# 5  7-4-2014 00:00:00
# 6 29-5-2014 00:00:00
```

Comment: Very clever!! I like it

Comment: When I use your suggestion, I got `Error in read.table(xx = as.character(df$varname)) :   unused argument (xx = as.character(df$varname))`

Comment: @Duna, where in my answer is "xx" used anywhere?

Comment: I tweaked your code to my actual data, and that was my name for text. Sorry, if I got it wrong!

Comment: @Duna, `text` is the argument for `read.table` that specifies to use a character vector rather than a file to create the `data.frame`.

Answer (score 4):

Other option (better)

```
# Convert to POSIXct objects
times <- as.POSIXct(dd$x, format="%d-%m-%Y %T")
# You may also want to specify the time zone    
times <- as.POSIXct(dd$x, format="%d-%m-%Y %T", tz="GMT")
```

Then, to extract times

```
strftime(times, "%T")
[1] "06:00:00" "12:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00"
```

or dates

```
strftime(times, "%D")
[1] "04/29/14" "04/09/14" "04/09/14" "05/06/14" "04/07/14" "05/29/14"
```

or, any format you want, really

```
strftime(times, "%d %b %Y at %T")
[1] "29 Apr 2014 at 06:00:00" "09 Apr 2014 at 12:00:00"
[3] "09 Apr 2014 at 00:00:00" "06 May 2014 at 00:00:00"
[5] "07 Apr 2014 at 00:00:00" "29 May 2014 at 00:00:00"
```

See, for more info: `?as.POSIXct` and `?strftime`

Comment: +1 Yes, this is better since they want actual date/time values.